# What is a "Compatability Definition Update" in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Today a recommended windows update, [KB3150513](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3150513/latest-compatibility-definition-update-for-windows), is a *Compatability Definition Update*

> This update provides the latest set of definitions for compatibility diagnostics that are performed on the system. The updated definitions help enable Microsoft and its partners to ensure compatibility for all customers who want to install the latest Windows operating system. Installing this update also makes sure that the latest Windows operating system version is correctly offered through Windows Update, based on compatibility results.

I have no idea what this means.

*For all customer's who want to install the latest operating system*. I already installed Windows, I don't plan on installing a newer version on top of it...?

Can you explain what this update actually does?

*Using Windows 7 SP1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an update that checks your installed software and reports to to Microsoft.

> For all customer's who want to install the latest operating system.

This update is helpful for Microsoft to test the compatibility while upgrading to Windows 10. If they detect any issues, updating to Windows 10 is done after uninstalling the buggy software/drivers.

Comment: I have no intention of updating to Windows 8 or 10. Can I ignore the update?

Comment: yes, in this case, simply hide the update each month in Windows Update.